# Compare field from previous row in JDBC ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I've researched can't find any relevant info. I have a result set that give me back distinct tagId's their can be multiple tagIds for same accountId's.

```
while(result_set.next()){
   String tagId = result_set.getString("tagId");
   String accountId = result_set.getString("accoundId");
   // plenty of other fields being store locally
}
```

I need to store first accoundId(which is being done) & every subsequent iteration compare it with the previous Id to check for equality or not(if so same account).

I tried this and it failed horribly, after first iteration they'll continually be equal & I must be DUMB bc i though as long as I compare them before assignment global guy(previousId) should be holding the prior value.

```
String previousId = null;  
while(result_set.next()){
   String tagId = result_set.getString("tagId");
   String accountId = result_set.getString("accoundId");
   previousId = accountId;
}
```

Anyway I wanted my workflow to go something as follows:

```
 while(result_set.next()){
     if (previousId = null) {
         // this would be the first iteration
     }
     else if (previousId.equals(accountId) {
        // go here
     } else {
      // go here
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you well, this should work..

```
String previousId = null;  
while(result_set.next()){
   String tagId = result_set.getString("tagId");
   String accountId = result_set.getString("accoundId");
   if (previousId == null) {
     // this would be the first iteration
   } else if (previousId.equals(accountId) {
    // go here
   } else {
     // go here
   }
   previousId = accountId;
}
```

Comment: check `if (previousId = null) {` will it compile

Comment: @MGorgon +1 for your answer